# SAS and Snowflake

Tags: sas, snowflake-schema

We are moving to Snowflake and I find running SAS Codes taking a lot more time than usual. This is because the variable lengths are very high (32767 length). How do I limit these variable lengths? Within Greenplum, I was able to limit the lengths using the VARCHAR() option but this doesn't seem to work with Snowflake. Any alternatives?

Comment: Given that in Snowflake you can define the length of VARCHAR datatypes, what do you mean by "but this doesn't seem to work with Snowflake"? Please can you provide some more detail e.g. table definitions, example data, example code, etc

Comment: Not in snowflake but when trying to access snowflake data via SAS. I tried something like First_Name :: varchar(50) as First_Name but that didn't change the length of the variable.

Comment: I'm not a SAS person but have seen this issue with a number of DBs where SAS was accessing it. I've been told that the "best practice is to set the lengths when creating variable length character columns" - if this helps? Also, just checking that you are using SQL pass-though?

Comment: Yeah, I have been trying that way. When it was accessing Greenplum a statement such as FIRST_NAME :: VARCHAR(50) AS FIRST_NAME would set the length of the Name to 50 but when I use the same with Snowflake, I don't see any change in the variable length. Yes, I'm using SQL pass-through. Appreciate your inputs.